# Trying to search two strings in a document in the same line

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

```
            WebClient wb = new WebClient();
            string License = wb.DownloadString("DocumentSite");
            if (License.Contains(LK.Text + UN.Text))
```

I want to search line by line and not the whole document

Comment: WebClient is deprecated. It's recommended to use the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use Regex for this. A positive lookahead for each string (prefixed by any number of characters), and anchored to the beginning of a line, should suffice

```cs
var regex = "^" + string.Concat(new[]{LK.Text, UN.Text}.Select(s => $"(?=.*?{s})"));
if (Regex.Match(licence, regex, RegexOptions.Multiline))
{
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `StringReader` to step through the string line by line.

```cs
private async Task ReadLicenseAsync(string license)
{
  using var textReader = new StringReader(license);
  string line = string.Empty;
  while ((line = await textReader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
  {
    // TODO::Handle line
  }
}
```